# why my vim color changed when connect to the tmux terminal?

Tags: linux, tmux

Environment:
vim7.3
secureCRT 5.1
CentOS  5

Screenshot: http://www.pureonebio.com/tmux.png

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.hawkhost.com/2010/07/02/tmux-%E2%80%93-the-terminal-multiplexer-part-2/#modifying-tab-color

http://blog.oldworld.fr/index.php?post/2010/03/21/256-colors-terminal-with-tmux-and-urxvt

The colour change may be due to the color support issues of the computer you use. Some support 256 where some do not. What is so special about colors when the usage is important? Anyway, have a good time.

Comment: Dark blue above black is about everything